# ASP.NET Configuration Transform not working

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Here is my (shortened) `Web.config`

```
<configuration>
  [...]
  <nlog autoReload="true" throwExceptions="false" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
      <target xsi:type="File" name="file" layout="[...]" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
</configuration>
```

This is my `Web.Release.Config`

```
<configuration>
  <nlog>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="#{Something}#" writeTo="file" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(writeTo)" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
</configuration>
```

Howere there is just no transform happening. Also I cant see any errors or warnings in the `ConfigurationTransform` output window...

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `nlog` element in the release config is in a different [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace), you need to include that:

```
<configuration>
  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd">
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="#{Something}#" writeTo="file"
          xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(writeTo)" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
</configuration>
```